# Cannot plot FFT results in GRC, gives "itemsize mismatch" error

Tags: plot, fft, gnuradio-companion

I'm trying to plot the spectrum of the HackRF received signal. I've made the flowchart below for that. However, when running it, gnuradio gives an error "itemsize mismatch" and references to the Stream to Vector block.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the FFT block in your flowgraph because the QT GUI Frequency Sink already does that. 
Connect your source directly to the QT GUI Frequency.